Does the mean of the maxima of a set of distributions converge?
This question is related to a recent one I posted. In that question I ask what statistic might best represent the central tendency of the true discrete distribution of a property  for a sample for which only a biased incomplete subset is available. In particular, the maxima from the samples are accurate but values smaller than this might be missing. This implies that statistics computed from the maxima are experimentally accurate. However, whereas increasing the sample size would improve the estimate of a mean (unless the distribution is incomplete, which the other question is about), I expect it will increasingly diverge for the maximum, as larger values are more likely to be observed in larger and more samples.
I am wondering however if there are useful (eg stable, converging, perhaps proportional to the mean) statistics representative of the population that can be computed from the sampled maxima?  For instance, does the mean of the maxima of a set of distributions converge (I suggested in the previous paragraph that it probably doesn't, but I am not a statistician)? Can I account for variations in the number of values in a distribution from which the statistic is computed?
Note the sample distribution is not necessarily normal and is expected to be biased (skewed) to larger values. Also, the values are necessarily positive (being particle lengths).

Although I think I follow your first paragraph, I cannot make sense of "mean of the maxima of a set of distributions."  Are you sure this is the question you want to ask?  If so, what exactly does "converging" mean in a set?

@whuber I think I will have to supplement the question with some graphics. This will take some time to put together.

@whuber if I take N samples from a distribution and pick the maximum, repeat this k times, compute the mean, will the mean converge to some value (for fixed N)? How will it depend on N? I think I've seen related questions (for instance for estimating the SD from max-min of the data. I suppose this is similar.  I suppose (max-min)/2 might provide an estimate of the mean, which is well behaved (converges). In my case however I have accurate maxes but no accurate mins, although I suppose I might estimate them.

The maximum is one sample from the distribution of the maximum of $N$ iid values.  As $k$ increases, the empirical mean will therefore converge to the expected value (see: WLLN), which has a simple expression in terms of the survival function of the underlying distribution.  Whether this expectation converges as $N$ increases depends on whether the support of the distribution has an upper bound.

@whuber Thanks, the LLN to the rescue (!). So a sample of maxima might be useful? The distributions have an experimental upper bound (the particles can only be so big).

That's useful, but it leads me to wonder how informative convergence results might be.

Consider the Cauchy distribution with N=1. If the procedure converged with increasing k, it would converge at the mean of the distribution, but the Cauchy distribution has no defined mean.

@whuber Not sure what you mean with that last statement. Ultimately I want to compare means of statistics (here maxes) from k distributions each with N samples from two populations assumed different (or same according to H0, particles of type A and B). I guess I can expect the uncertainty in the statistic "maximum" to be more uncertain? Is that it? Also, N potentially differs in the k samples.

@NuclearHoagie The experimental distribution is bounded at zero and at high values. It might look like a Cauchy distribution where it was sampled, but is curtailed at the extremes. For a truly unbounded distribution, I would expect that as $N \to \inf $ so would the average of the maximum.

Your question appears to conflate what you want to estimate with how you want to estimate it.  It sounds like you have run $k$ experiments in which the maxima of $N_1,\ldots,N_k$ iid samples from a common distribution have been observed; and then you have repeated this with $m$ similar experiments from a potentially different distribution.  But what do you want to estimate or test?

“Order statistics” might be of interest to you.

@whuber Intuitively yes, and this is how I'd have treated the data, but it turns out here a replicate is a collection of distributions. As an analogy, think of a growing crystal with many "thorns", where each thorn is one particle, and a replicate is a collection of crystals growing in a dish (each dish is a replicate). I want to identify an appropriate statistic to represent each replicate. We seed the crystals and the number of growing crystals varies between dishes. I can measure the size of the multiple particles growing in a crystal. I can also sum those lengths etc.

I am interested in finding what dish conditions result in the "best" crystals. In parallel I am looking into a gravimetric approach but image analysis might accelerate screening (gravimetry can't tell me whether crystals in a dish are growing).

" does the mean of the maxima of a set of distributions converge" This is not very clear, converge while increasing what? The sample size based on which the maxima is computed, or the number of samples from which a maximum is computed? Process the explanations that you give in your comments into the question.

If the domains of the distributions are bounded above, as one of your comments above would indicate, then yes, as the sample size $\to \infty$, the mean of the maxima will converge, as the maxima themselves will converge to the upper bounds.
